# How to count rows over multiple joins

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I have a complex (for my SQL standard) count I need to perform over multiple tables I'd love some help with.

I have three tables:

RELEASE

```
ID    |METADATA_ID|Is_Active|Creation_Source|Release_Status
123456|123        | Y       | A1            |Active
134567|124        | Y       | A1            |Active
145678|125        | N       | A2            |Closed
```

RELEASE_METADATA

```
ID     |UPC
123    |8001   
124    |8002
125    |8003
```

RELEASE_COUNTRY_RIGHT

```
(RELEASE)ID |COUNTRY_ID|MARKETING_RIGHT|OPT_OUT
123456      |   UK     |    N          |N    
123456      |   US     |    Y          |N   
123456      |   FR     |    Y          |Y    
134567      |   UK     |    Y          |N    
134567      |   US     |    Y          |Y   
145678      |   UK     |    Y          |Y    
145678      |   FR     |    Y          |N
```

I need to be able to filter the results by the Source and Status from RELEASE, include the UPC from RELEASE_METADATAand count the related number of rows, Marketing and Selected fields from RELEASE_COUNTRY_RIGHT.

So my result would be something like:

```
ID    |Is_Active|Creation_Source|Release_Status|UPC |RELEASE_COUNTRY_RIGHT Rows|MARKETING_RIGHT|OPT_OUT    
123456| Y       |   A1          |Active        |8001| 3                        |  2            |  1  
134567| Y       |   A1          |Active        |8002| 2                        |  2            |  1
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Update:
I've tried using SHALAKA's solution below but i'm having trouble after substituting the table and field names as shown below. I've updated the table and fields names above as I realized that what I had may have been misleading.
There is also an additional field which I missed out as the joins are not as I expected.
RELEASE joins with RELEASE_METADATA via release.ID = release_metadata_id and the third table needs to join by release.ID = release_country_right.release_ID.

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT grp_1.*, COUNT(a5.OPT_OUT) OPT_OUT
      FROM (SELECT grp.*, COUNT(a4.MARKETING_RIGHT) MARKETING_RIGHT
              FROM (SELECT a1.id,
                           a1.IS_ACTIVE,
                           a1.CREATION_SOURCE,
                           a1.RELEASE_STATUS,
                           a2.upc,
                           COUNT(a3.RELEASE_ID) a_row
                      FROM dschd.release a1, dschd.release_metadata a2, DSCHD.RELEASE_COUNTRY_RIGHT a3
                     WHERE a1.RELEASE_METADATA_ID = a2.id
                       AND a1.id = a3.RELEASE_ID
                       AND a1.IS_ACTIVE = 'Y'
                     GROUP BY a1.id, a1.IS_ACTIVE, a1.CREATION_SOURCE, a1.RELEASE_STATUS, a2.UPC) grp,
                   DSCHD.RELEASE_COUNTRY_RIGHT a4
             WHERE a4.OPT_OUT = grp.id
               AND a4.MARKETING_RIGHT = 'N'
             GROUP BY grp.id,
                      grp.IS_ACTIVE,
                      grp.CREATION_SOURCE,
                      grp.RELEASE_STATUS,
                      grp.upc,
                      grp.a_row) grp_1,
           DSCHD.RELEASE_COUNTRY_RIGHT a5
     WHERE a5.RELEASE_ID = grp_1.id
       AND a5.OPT_OUT = 'Y'
     GROUP BY grp_1.id,
              grp_1.IS_ACTIVE,
              grp_1.CREATION_SOURCE,
              grp_1.RELEASE_STATUS,
              grp_1.upc,
              grp_1.a_row,
              grp_1.MARKETING_RIGHT
```

Comment: Add a new line before "the block" and add 4 spaces between every line ( this can be done selecting the block, and pressing Ctrl + K ). Your post will look better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT grp_1.*, COUNT(a5.selected) selected
  FROM (SELECT grp.*, COUNT(a4.marketing) marketing
          FROM (SELECT a1.id,
                       a1.active,
                       a1.source,
                       a1.status,
                       a2.ref,
                       COUNT(a3.id) a_row
                  FROM data1 a1, data2 a2, data3 a3
                 WHERE a1.id = a2.id
                   AND a2.id = a3.id
                   AND a1.active = 'Y'
                 GROUP BY a1.id, a1.active, a1.source, a1.status, a2.ref) grp,
               data3 a4
         WHERE a4.id = grp.id
           AND a4.marketing = 'Y'
         GROUP BY grp.id,
                  grp.active,
                  grp.source,
                  grp.status,
                  grp.ref,
                  grp.a_row) grp_1,
       data3 a5
 WHERE a5.id = grp_1.id
   AND a5.selected = 'Y'
 GROUP BY grp_1.id,
          grp_1.active,
          grp_1.source,
          grp_1.status,
          grp_1.ref,
          grp_1.a_row,
          grp_1.marketing
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't put the original tables and fields names I tried to simplify them for the sake of the forum. However when I tried your suggestion, it didn't work after I substituted the tables and fields. My attempt is in the main post but I keep getting: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.